How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{e^t-1})\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$?
I’m reading George E. Andrews’ Special Functions, and it says the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{t} +
\frac{1}{{\rm e}^{t} - 1}\right)\frac{{\rm e}^{-t}}{t}\,{\rm d}t
$$
can be calculated using Stirling’s Formula in page $28$, and the answer is
$$
1 - \frac{1}{2}\,\log\left(2\pi\right)
$$
but I can’t figure it out. Anyone can help ?.

You have to prove one of Binet's formulae http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.E10_2

@Gary Thanks for your reply, but I’m going to prove it

This paper proves it.

You can use analytical continuation to get the answer.
Denoting the desired integral as $I_{-1}$, let's consider
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac12-\frac{1}{t}+\frac1{e^t-1}\right)e^{-t}t^\alpha dt$$
taking $\alpha>0$, we can handle every integral separately, and in the end define $I(\alpha)$ at $\alpha=-1$.
$$I_1=\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^\alpha dt=\frac12\Gamma(1+\alpha)\tag{1}$$
$$I_2=-\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{\alpha-1} dt=-\Gamma(\alpha)\tag{2}$$
$$I_3=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{e^t-1}-e^{-t}\right)t^\alpha dt=\Gamma(1+\alpha)\zeta(1+\alpha)-\Gamma(1+\alpha)\tag{3}$$
Denoting $x=1+\alpha\,\,(\,\to 0\,)$, using $\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}x$, and taking together (1), (2), (3)
$$I(x)=\Gamma(x)\zeta(x)-\frac{\Gamma(x)}{x-1}-\frac{\Gamma(x)}2=\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}x\left(\zeta(x)+\frac1{1-x}-\frac12\right)$$
Decomposing $\Gamma(1+x)=1-\gamma x+O(x^2)$ and $\zeta(x)=\zeta(0)+\zeta'(0)x+O(x^2)=-\frac12-\frac{\ln(2\pi)}2x+O(x^2)$,
we see that the diverging terms cancel, and we finally get
$$I_{-1}=\lim_{x\to0}I(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\zeta(0)+\frac12}x+\zeta'(0)-\gamma\zeta(0)+1-\frac\gamma2+O(x)\right)=1-\frac{\ln(2\pi)}2$$

Nice solution. (+1)

@Alann Rosas, thank you :)
